# Allow space at the end of p{L} in Regex

Tags: regex

I have following regular expression in my validator :

```
validator.addValidation(userNameLayout, "[\\p{L}\\ \\'\\-\\,\\.]+[\\p{L}//]", context.resources.getString(R.string.verification_userdata_name_invalid))
```

Is there any solution to allow just whitespace at the end of `p{L}` and nothing else?

So it is possible to enter :   `ali rezaei`

but it is not possible to enter : `ali.`

Now I have added this `+[\S]` to end of regex :

`"[\\p{L}\\ \\'\\-\\,\\.]+[\\p{L}//]+[\\s]"`

It allows a single space at the end but not multiple spaces. What is the solution?

Comment: If you need help, please share a code pen and a test case, it not possible to help you without seeing your relevant code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I edited my question, please take a short look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex:

```js
"[-\\p{L}\\s',.]*\\p{L}\\s*"
```

used in `validator.addValidation()`, should match the string that fully matches

- `[-\p{L} ',.]*` - any zero or more letters, `-`, whitespaces, apostrophes, commas, dots
- `\p{L}` - a Unicode letter
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars (optional trailing whitespaces).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wulK6u/1).